# No photo for configurable product in cart

Tags: magento2, cart

After added product to the basket no display photo for configurable product.

In magento photo have only main product. Sizes no have photo. (simple product work perfect).

[image]

@ update

[image]

I dont know why magento download photo from sizes (variants) no from main product.

Any one know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the issue for me:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/108c2c5f6353bf977508baa20cef200521eb247d

It's supposed to be fixed in 2.2.6

Comment: @ Sabel in app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ImageBuilder.php I no have folder Magento and File imagebuidler.php Do you now when I can found this file  in other location ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not added images to the simple product associated to the configurable product.

Go to the configurable product.

Go under configurations

You will see all associated products

add images to the product who does not have image

Comment: In my other stores I never added photo for simple product associated to the configurable product and photo is displayed correct in basket.

Answer (score 0):

Check below config

Store => Configurations => Sales => Checkout => Shopping cart => Configurable product image

Select: Parent product thumbnail

Comment: MageX thanks for your reply. Please check I updated my topic.